# Grep for URL parsing - bash script programming

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

I am trying to learn some bash scripting and i can't understand how to use `grep` in order to split a URL link for example :

```
blabla1.com         
blabla2.gov         
blabla3.fr
```

I just want to keep com , gov and fr ( without the '.' character) ignore whats before '.'

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: That is not what grep is for. `grep` is an abbreviation for "**G**lobally find a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the result". What you are describing is a job for some other tool like `sed` or `awk`. If your URLs are included among other text in files, post some samples of that full text. Also post exactly what your expected output would be given your posted sample input.

Comment: @Ed Morton You are right.. `grep` is not what I wanted in the end because it only prints .. I think `awk` is more suitable ( I am studying on it ) ! sorry for the late answer

Comment: It depends what you are really trying to do. If you're doing a simple substitution on individual lines then sed is the right tool. If it's more than that then you'd use awk. We can't tell from what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep is a tool for *matching* text.  You need something else if you want to *transform* text.  If you have the values in question in a bash variable, then what you ask is pretty easy:

```
authority=blabla.com

# Here's the important bit:
domain=${authority/*./}

echo $domain
```

The funny syntax in the middle evaluates to the result of a pattern substitution on the value of variable `temp`.

If you're trying to do this on lines of a file, then the `sed` program is your friend:

```
sed 's/.*\.//' < input.file
```

This is again a pattern substitution, but `sed` uses regular expression patterns, whereas bash uses shell glob patterns.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E -o '[^.]+$' < input
```

-o  instructs grep to print only the matching part of the line

-E  switches on extended regexp which is needed for + quantifier

[^.]+$  means any character which is not a dot at the end of the line

Comment: @User1911 a tool that produces the output you want from some specific sample input is just the starting point for a solution. The above is unnecessarily complex if all you want is the part after a `.` in a file, other tools can do it more simply and portably.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
grep -o -E '[a-z]{2,3}\b' input > output
```

`-o, --only-matching`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

```
$ cat input
blabla1.com
blabla2.gov
blabla3.fr

$ cat output
com
gov
fr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -d. -f2 file
com
gov
fr
```

If that's not all you need, post some more truly representative input and expected output so we can help you find the right solution.